# Why does FormData cause 400 bad request?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

**UPDATE 3**:

```
//program.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Zeel.Onboarding.DataModels;
using Zeel.Onboarding.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<PageMapManager, PageMapManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TranslationManager, TranslationManager>();

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

**UPDATE 2**:
This is the code that's actually working perfectly as expected. You can see where I swapped the commented code. Don't be fooled by `contentType` and `processData` and `dataType`, I tried all manner of values and combinations.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#editLocalFormJs", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var myform = $("#frmItemLocalForm");
        var valid = myform.valid();

        if (valid) {

            var formData = new FormData();

            $(".fileUpload").each(function () {
                var fileInput = $(this)[0];
                var file = fileInput.files[0];

                formData.append($(this).attr("id"), file);
            });

            formData.append("myFormData", myform.serialize());

            $.ajax({
                url: "/pageprocessing/saveuserreference",
                data: formData,//myform.serialize(),
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: false,//"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                processData: false,
                method: "post",
                //type: "post",
                success: function (result) {
                    $(".close-button").click();
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the controller endpoint

```
public void SaveUserReference()
{
   ...
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Some weird behaviour. If I post to a controller it works and I get files and data. However, if I post to the page itself (Razor code behind) `public void OnPost(...)` I get the 400 error. It's almost like the page can't find itself, which is also weird because other methods on that page `OnGet` and `OnGetData` work with no issue.

The error that gets shown in the browser console is here

[image]

If you click the links it goes to the page so I know the path is valid.

I put everything on the page so that it's self-contained and I can reuse the page anywhere, and I don't have to worry about changes elsewhere breaking that page, nor changes to that page breaking anything else. The pages are data-driven, so configured via a database, I have around 7 or 8 pages (of this type) and they all work just fine, but this is the first of this type that has file upload as part of its functionality.

---

**THE PROBLEM**:
I have the following situation. This works perfectly, but when I try to use `formData` to enable file upload I get a 400 (bad request) error. I have tried all manner of content-type and enctype, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

You can see the commented lines. if I switch to those I always get a 400 'bad request'

Visual Studio 2022, Net 8.

My Form (BS5 Modal)

```
<form id="frmItemLocalForm" method="post" name="frmItemLocalForm" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="controlId" id="controlId" value="@ViewData["controlid"]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId" value="@ViewData["itemId"]" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserDocument.Created" name="Created" />

    <!--Modal Header-->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User Document</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row my-1">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" asp-for="UserDocument.DocumentName" name="DocumentName" data-rule-required="true" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row my-1">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2">File</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control fileUpload" placeholder="User Document" name="userdocumentfileupload" id="userdocumentfileupload" data-rule-required="true" required />
                <br />@Model.UserDocument?.DocumentName @Model.UserDocument?.FileName
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="editLocalForm" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger close-button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$(document).on("click", "#editLocalForm", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var myform = $("#frmItemLocalForm");
    var valid = myform.valid();

    if (valid) {

        var formData = new FormData();

        //$(".fileUpload").each(function () {
        //    var fileInput = $(this)[0];
        //    var file = fileInput.files[0];

        //    if (file.size > 0) {
        //        formData.append($(this).attr("id"), file);
        //    }
        //});

        //formData.append("myFormData", myform.serialize());

        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            data: myform.serialize(),//formData,
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            processData: false,
            method: "post",
            success: function (result) {
                $(".close-button").click();
                table.ajax.reload(null, false);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Server End Point.
I have a break point here that doesn't even get hit

```
public void OnPost()
{
    ... Request.Form.Files...

}
```

Comment: What does your server endpoint look like?

Comment: Post the whole form, especially the `AntiForgeryToken`.

Comment: Makes no difference :(

Comment: don't set content-type, FormData will already set headers properly.  The main issue is you are serializing... just do   thisForm = document.getElementById('frmItemLocalForm');
    var formData = new FormData(thisForm);  And send formData via ajax... ex: data: formData

Comment: also check value of formUrl....   if valid check doesn't pass or is null make sure you have  validation script included... i.e. _ValidationScriptsPartial @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");} }

Comment: also note that $("#frmItemLocalForm"); is a jQuery object... you don't want that.  Use document.getElementById...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` or maybe `contentType: false`?

With those contentType, you can send `myform` without serializing it inside the `data` of your ajax

Comment: Yep tried all of those. The only way it seems to work is if I post to a Controller. Posting to `OnPost`  stops working as soon as I start using `FormData`, regardless of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Razor Pages enable anti-forgery token validation by default, so you need add this token to header in ajax. Otherwise you may receive 400 Bad Request error.

If you use ajax post the data with file input, it should be:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

Also you need use FormData instead of `form.serialize()`.

A whole working demo:

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form id="frmItemLocalForm" method="post" name="frmItemLocalForm" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="controlId" id="controlId" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserDocument.Created" name="Created" value="created2" />

    <!--Modal Header-->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User Document</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row my-1">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" asp-for="UserDocument.DocumentName" name="DocumentName" data-rule-required="true" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row my-1">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2">File</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control fileUpload" placeholder="User Document" name="userdocumentfileupload" id="userdocumentfileupload" data-rule-required="true" required />
                <br />@Model.UserDocument?.DocumentName @Model.UserDocument?.FileName
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="editLocalForm" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger close-button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).on("click", "#editLocalForm", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                var myform = $("#frmItemLocalForm");
                var valid = myform.valid();

                if (valid) {

                    var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append("userdocumentfileupload", $('.fileUpload')[0].files[0]);
                formData.append("userDocument.Created", $('input[name="Created"]').val());
                formData.append("userDocument.DocumentName", $('input[name="DocumentName"]').val());
                formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
                    console.log(key, value);
                });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Index",
                         data: formData,
                        dataType: "html",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        method: "post",
                    headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken:
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                            $(".close-button").click();
                            //table.ajax.reload(null, false);
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public UserDocument UserDocument { get; set; }
    public void OnPost(UserDocument userDocument,IFormFile userdocumentfileupload) 
    { 
    }
}
public class UserDocument
{
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string? FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Tried all of those too. Something is going on, the only way this works is if I post to a controller. Using `form.serialize()` doesn't attach any files. The only way I can get it to work is using formData

Comment: Hi @djack109, could you pls share your current modified code and Program.cs?

Comment: Thanks for that Info. I updated my question :) I'm pretty sure I did try what you suggested but to no avail. It's working for now but I will go back to it when I have some time as I want to get to the bottom of it. I'll post an update.

Comment: Hi @djack109, so the code works for mvc controller instead of razor pages? Have your add the token in header like my shared answer?

Comment: Yep. I did that. It's like it can't find the method on the page. Its really weird

Comment: Hi @djack109, ` It's like it can't find the method on the page` it seems not, because if it does not find the method, it would be 404 error, but you receive 400 error. Could you pls also share the Program.cs?

Comment: program.cs in UPDATE 3

Comment: Hi @djack109, It think it is better for you to share a minimal repo which could reproduce the issue. I test in my side with your current code and works fine.

Comment: I haven't come back to it yet but when I do I will put a repo up. As I have a workaround its less of a priority